# Building R packages (C API) with Visual Studio

Tags: c, r, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, r-package

I'm trying to build a simple R package with Visual Studio, here is my code:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP add(SEXP a, SEXP b) {
  SEXP result = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP, 1));
  REAL(result)[0] = asReal(a) + asReal(b);
  UNPROTECT(1);

  return result;
}
```

I have R runtime and RTools installed.

When I try to compile it, I get the following link error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol REAL referenced in function "struct SEXPREC * __cdecl add(struct SEXPREC *,struct SEXPREC *)" (?add@@YAPEAUSEXPREC@@PEAU1@0@Z)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Rf_asReal referenced in function "struct SEXPREC * __cdecl add(struct SEXPREC *,struct SEXPREC *)" (?add@@YAPEAUSEXPREC@@PEAU1@0@Z)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Rf_allocVector referenced in function "struct SEXPREC * __cdecl add(struct SEXPREC *,struct SEXPREC *)" (?add@@YAPEAUSEXPREC@@PEAU1@0@Z)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Rf_protect referenced in function "struct SEXPREC * __cdecl add(struct SEXPREC *,struct SEXPREC *)" (?add@@YAPEAUSEXPREC@@PEAU1@0@Z)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol Rf_unprotect referenced in function "struct SEXPREC * __cdecl add(struct SEXPREC *,struct SEXPREC *)" (?add@@YAPEAUSEXPREC@@PEAU1@0@Z)
```

Well, I guess that i'm missing some binaries that are required for the linking process. The problem is that I have no idea where can I find the necessary `.lib` files. Inside the R runtime installation folder I can find the `include` directory, but I cannot find any `lib` directory. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I do not think that the standard binary installations of R have the files you need. I know that *nix users need to install an expanded set of files in order to have the correct header files available.

Comment: See the R Installation and Administration manual section on [the Windows toolset](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset) -- basically, you'll have a very difficult time using Visual Studio, and instead need to use MinGW-based Rtools.

Comment: Could you try VS2015 which supports R natively? Maybe the problem can be fixed sometime? Btw, `.C()` can work with VS, example [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/accelerate-r-applications-cuda/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allow me to quote from the [Rcpp FAQ](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.Rnw) vignette:

> **Can I use `Rcpp` with Visual Studio ?**
>
> Not a chance.
>
> And that is not because we are meanies but because `R` and Visual
>   Studio simply do not get along. As `Rcpp` is all about extending
>   `R` with `C++` interfaces, we are bound by the available
>   toolchain.  And `R` simply does not compile with Visual Studio. Go
>   complain to its vendor if you are still upset.

Microsoft more or less went out of its way to ensure what its OS and tooling were not POSIX compliant.  As R grew up in a Unix / POSIX world there simply is a gap you cannot bridge (easily).

So on Windows the MinGW port of gcc it is.